# C++ How to parse math problem in string using TinyExpr?

Tags: visual-c++

First I need to detect if message from player contains math problem
like I get 2 messages from him

```
char* message1 = "Please solve this math problem";
char* message2 = "How much is 1 + 2 ?";
```

These messages are not static, player can say different messages.

I need to process message1 and message2
I need to detect math problem and cut it like see message2 and I need it to be "1+2"

```
char* mathProblemFromMessage = "1+2"; // <- I need to get this from message also detect if message contains any math problem before

double answer = te_interp(mathProblemFromMessage, 0);

printf("Answer is %f\n", answer);
```

my current code

```
std::string msg = Message;

if (func.contains_math_operators(msg.c_str()) && func.contains_number(msg.c_str()))
{
    double answer = te_interp(Message, 0);
}
```

I think it fails and always results 0 because msg is "Player: 1+1" I need to cut math problem from it, I dont know how to do it...a

Answer (score 0):

Find a position of the first digit in that string and get a substring from that point:

```
std::size_t found = msg.find_first_of("0123456789");
if(found != std::string::npos)
{
  std::string sub = msg.substr(found);
  double answer = te_interp(sub, 0);
}
```

If that also fails, try to trim invalid tail.

You may want to extend that `find_first_of` above to include open paren `(`, unary minus `-` or some supported function names (I am not familiar with TinyExpr)